# Meta_query date issue

Tags: wordpress

Hi I'm trying to display all events from today. Its a custom field so its being stored in the postmeta table. When I try and compare dates its returning no results when there should be. I'm matching the correct date format.

```
    $today = date('d/m/Y',time());
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'live',
'meta_query' => array(
                  array(
               'key' => 'date',
               'value' => $today,
               'compare' => '>=',
               'type' => 'DATE',
 )
)
);
```

Any help and I would be grateful.

Thanks

Comment: The custom field is updated using a jquery ui calendar. The database entry for date is in the same format date('d/m/Y',time()).

Comment: d/m/Y is not a good choice to compare dates, you should use Y/m/d

Answer (score 1):

To be able to compare dates, you should use Y/m/d format (or Y-m-d ...etc).

With your args, SQL query will be :

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'live' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') AND ( (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'date' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS DATE) >= '17/04/2012') ) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Which is wrong, for example `18/03/2012 >= 17/04/2012` is true...

If you use Y/m/d format and following args :

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'live',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'date',
            'value' => date('Y/m/d',time()),
            'compare' => '>=',
        )
    )
);
```

It will work as expecting :

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'live' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') AND ( (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'date' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) >= '2012/04/17') ) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

So :

- You can modify your date values in database
- Or you can build your own query to convert these values before comparison

Comment: Sorry I tried both of you suggestions and still no joy. I just printed out the last wordpress query and it looks like its not even comparing values

        SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'live' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10